# Converting a MongoDB aggregate into an ArangoDB COLLECT

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm migrating data from Mongo to Arango and I need to reproduce a $group aggregation. I have successfully reproduced the results but I'm concerned that my approach maybe sub-optimal. Can the AQL be improved?

I have a collection of data that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b17f9d85b2c1998598f054e"),
    "department" : [ 
        "Sales", 
        "Marketing"
    ],
    "region" : [ 
        "US", 
        "UK"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1808145b2c1998598f054f"),
    "department" : [ 
        "Sales", 
        "Marketing"
    ],
    "region" : [ 
        "US", 
        "UK"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b18083c5b2c1998598f0550"),
    "department" : "Development",
    "region" : "Europe"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1809a75b2c1998598f0551"),
    "department" : "Sales"
}
```

Note the value can be a string, Array or not present

In Mongo I'm using the following code to aggregate the data:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $unwind:{
        path:"$department",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{
    $unwind:{
        path:"$region",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{
    $group:{
        _id:{
            department:{ $ifNull: [ "$department", "null" ] },
            region:{ $ifNull: [ "$region", "null" ] },
        },
        count:{$sum:1}
    }
}
])
```

In Arango I'm using the following AQL:

```
FOR i IN test
    LET FIELD1=(FOR a IN APPEND([],NOT_NULL(i.department,"null")) RETURN a)
    LET FIELD2=(FOR a IN APPEND([],NOT_NULL(i.region,"null")) RETURN a)

    FOR f1 IN FIELD1
        FOR f2 IN FIELD2
            COLLECT id={department:f1,region:f2} WITH COUNT INTO counter

            RETURN {_id:id,count:counter}
```

Edit:
The APPEND is used to convert string values into an Array

Both produce results that look like this;

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Marketing",
        "region" : "US"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Development",
        "region" : "Europe"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Sales",
        "region" : "null"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Marketing",
        "region" : "UK"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Sales",
        "region" : "UK"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "department" : "Sales",
        "region" : "US"
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems alright. I would suggest to use `TO_ARRAY()` instead of `APPEND()` to make it easier to understand though.

Both functions skip null values, thus it is unavoidable to provide some placeholder, or test for *null* explicitly and return an array with a *null* value (or whatever works best for you):

```
FOR doc IN test
    FOR field1 IN doc.department == null ? [ null ] : TO_ARRAY(doc.department)
    FOR field2 IN doc.region == null ? [ null ] : TO_ARRAY(doc.region)
    COLLECT department = field1, region = field2
    WITH COUNT INTO count
        RETURN { _id: { department, region }, count }
```

Collection *test*:

```
[
  {
    "_key": "5b17f9d85b2c1998598f054e",
    "department": [
      "Sales",
      "Marketing"
    ],
    "region": [
      "US",
      "UK"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_key": "5b18083c5b2c1998598f0550",
    "department": "Development",
    "region": "Europe"
  },
  {
    "_key": "5b1808145b2c1998598f054f",
    "department": [
      "Sales",
      "Marketing"
    ],
    "region": [
      "US",
      "UK"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_key": "5b1809a75b2c1998598f0551",
    "department": "Sales"
  }
]
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Development",
      "region": "Europe"
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Marketing",
      "region": "UK"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Marketing",
      "region": "US"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Sales",
      "region": null
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Sales",
      "region": "UK"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "department": "Sales",
      "region": "US"
    },
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know I was on the right track. Your version was much cleaner though!